# CSS Responsive Desgn Footer taking whole space when screen size goes below 1180 px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As soon as I am reducing screen size to below 1180 px width, strange issue is occurring and right after header, thick black footer line(As seen in inspect element) is appearing just above slideshow.
When I am looking at inspect element, header and other body element is showing height of "0". Can any one please guide me what is messed up here. Everything is fine when screen size is more than 1180 px

here is the site where i am getting these issue: http://goo.gl/8c1gW2

Comment: Found the problem and a nice design responsive :)

Comment: Thanks Anobik, and please let me know what you found

Comment: Have found the issue even forund a break to it but trying for a more solid one Ill keep you updated currently working on that only :)

Comment: Take a look and Let me know :)

Comment: ok ok sorry sorry I actually wanted to make u clear every thing properly. Did not intend to do any harm :) please accept this answer if it suited you :) if some thing is left then you can Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, actual problem is that once screen is reduced below 1180 px, all menu disappears and <div class="respMenu noscroll"> gets hidden somewere behind some other element. So trying to figure out what is breaking this functionlaity.

Comment: ok ill also give a look and let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) :)

basically theres a `#headerwrap{position:relative; margin-bottom:30px;padding-bottom: 20px; min-height: 70px; float: left;}`

in the css name **irms_default.css?ver=3.6.1**

Heres the part of the css

```
@media screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1180px){
body{/*overflow:hidden;*/text-align:center;}
.aq_block_faq, .testimonial-texts, .aq-posts-block {text-align:left;}
.testimonial-description {background:#000000;}
.breadcrumb-info{display:inline-block; float:none;}
/*footer*/
#footer{top:20px;}
.footer_widget1{margin-top: 30px; }
.twitterlink,.facebooklink,.vimeo,.dribble,.emaillink{float:none; padding:13px;}
.footer_widget .widgett{margin:5px auto 15px auto !important; padding:0;}
#footerb .copyright{padding-top:0px; margin-top:-4px;width:95% !important; text-align:left !important;}
.footer_widget .widget_search form div {padding:0;}
.socialfooter .socialcategory{width:225px; float:none; margin:0 auto; display: inline-block;}
.footer_widget .category_posts .widgett, .footer_widget .recent_posts .widgett{float:none;}

/*menu + header*/
#headerwrap{position:relative; margin-bottom:30px;padding-bottom: 20px; min-height: 70px; float: left;}
#logo {width:100%;float:left;position:relative; }
```

If you can edit it then its fine. Else give inline css **#headerwrap** as `style="margin:0px"` and test :) let me know the results :)